# HomeKit completion block in Swift: Cannot convert the expression's type 'Void' to type 'String!'

Tags: ios, closures, swift, homekit

I'm playing with HomeKit, and I'm trying to add a new home. This is my code:

```
func addHome()
{
    homeManager.addHomeWithName("My House", completionHandler:
        { (error: NSError!, home: HMHome!) in
            if error
            {
                NSLog("%@", error)
            }
        })
}
```

This gives a compiler error:

> ```
> Cannot convert the expression's type 'Void' to type 'String!'
> ```

I've tried specifying a return type of `Void`:

```
...
{ (error: NSError!, home: HMHome!) -> Void in
...
```

to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this? Passing `nil` to the completion handler fixes the error, but of course I want to do something on completion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parameters for your completionHandler closure are reversed, they should be:

```
(home: HMHome!, error: NSError!)
```

Also note that you don't need to specify the types for the parameters, since the method signature specified them for you - thus you can simply list the parameter names you want to use, and they will automatically be assured to be of the correct type, for example:

```
homeManager.addHomeWithName("My House", completionHandler:{
    home, error in
    if error { NSLog("%@", error) }
    })
```

--*edit*--

Also note that when I wrote *'you can simply list the parameter names you want to use, and they will automatically be assured to be of the correct type'*, that is to say that they will be typed according to the order in which they are listed - e.g. if you had used `error, home in` instead, then those would be your parameter names however the parameter `error` would be of type `HMHome!`, and `home` would be of type `NSError!` (since that is the order in which they appear in the parameter list for the closure in the method's signature)

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments are ordered inconsistently; the signature for the `completionHandler` in `addHomeWithName` is

```
(HMHome!, NSError!) -> Void
```

thus use:

```
homeManager.addHomeWithName ("My House", completionHandler:
  { (home: HMHome!, error: NSError!) in
      if error { NSLog("%@", error) }} )
```

Using a trailing closure and allowing the compiler to infer the types lets you simplify the above to:

```
homeManager.addHomeWithName ("My House") {
  if $1 { NSLog ("%@", $1) }
}
```